# MongoDB bulkWrite in NodeJS causes a memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am currently trying to read a 23GB CSV file into MongoDB under NodeJS and am using the bulkWrite function for this as I also want to do updates etc. here.

My problem is that I call the bulkWrite function in my loop every `X` CSV entries and notice a steadily increasing memory consumption until the script runs into a memory exception at the end.

I'm using `node-mongodb-native` in version `4.12.1` and also tried `4.10`.

Here is my simplified script to test this problem.

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import fs from "fs";

const uri = "mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
const database = client.db("test");
const collection = database.collection("data");
const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./files/large-data.csv", "utf-8");
var docs = [];

async function writData(docs) {
    collection.bulkWrite(
        docs.map((doc) => ({
            insertOne: {
                prop: doc,
            },
        })),
        {
            writeConcern: { w: 0, j: false },
            ordered: false,
        }
    );
}

readStream.on("data", async function (chunk) {
    docs.push(chunk.toString());

    if (docs.length >= 100) {
        var cloneData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docs)); // https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-608
        docs = [];
        await writData(cloneData);
    }
});
```

I tried a lot of stuff most important if I comment out the `await writeData(cloneData);` line the script runs with a stable memory consumption of 100MB but if I use the function the memory consumption increases to multiple GB until it crashes.

I also tried to expose the garbage collection `--expose-gc` and placed `global.gc();` into my if statement but it doesn't helped.

So for me it looks like `collection.bulkWrite` store some information somewhere that I need to clean up but I can't find any information about it. It would be great if anyone has any ideas or experience on what else I can try.

Answer (score 0):

use [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream) split and send on streams.

```js
import fs from "fs"
import es from "event-stream"

fs.createReadStream(filename)
  .pipe(es.split()) 
  .pipe(es.parse())
```